# Reading a structure from a binary file in c++

Tags: c++, file, file-io

So I'm trying to read a structure from a binary file that I write but something seems to be wrong. Here is my main:

```
//Fraction structure
struct Fraction
{
int num, den;
};


int main()
{
int menu_selection;
char slash;

fstream datafile; //creates file object
Fraction* f; //creates pointer for dam

//menu to the user
menu_selection = main_menu();
bool condition = true;
while (condition)
{
    switch(menu_selection)
    {
    case 1: //adds a new Fraction structure to binary file
        f = new Fraction; //dynamically allocating memory
        cout << "Enter fraction to add: "; //adds fraction to file
        cin >> f->num >> slash >> f->den;//stores input
        datafile.open("fractions.dat",ios:: out | ios:: app | ios::binary); //creates file
        datafile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(f),sizeof(Fraction));//stores fraction to file
        datafile.close();
        menu_selection = main_menu();
        break;
    case 2:
        menu_selection = main_menu();
        break;
    case 3: //displays the contents of the file to user
        datafile.open("fractions.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);
        while(!datafile.eof())
        {
            datafile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(f),sizeof(f));
            cout << f->num << "/" << f->den << " ";
        }
        datafile.close();
        menu_selection = main_menu();
        break;
    case 4:
        menu_selection = main_menu();
        break;
    case 5:
        menu_selection = main_menu();
        break;
    case 6: condition = false;
        return 0;
        break;
    default: cout << endl << "That is an invalid option. Please try again." << endl; //default option
        break;
    }
}
delete f;
}
```

When the user enters 1 I dynamically allocate memory for the structure Fraction and writes it to a binary file. I use ios::app because I want to add on to the file when it is called again. Is there anything wrong with either the writing or the reading functions? Whenever I run the program as it is, if I input one fraction such as 1/5, it shows 1/5 5/5 5/5, however if I input two fractions such as 1/5 and 2/6, it shows 2/6 6/6 6/6.

Comment: and I will worry about error testing later.

Comment: Most of your variables are not properly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
    datafile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(f),sizeof(Fraction));//stores fraction to file
```

That doesn't make any sense. You have to convert the class instance to a binary format to store it. You can't just tell the compiler to pretend you did that when you actually didn't!

Files are streams of bytes. To store something in a file, you have to have a format for that something that is specified in terms of a stream (or chunk) of bytes. You can't just trick the compiler into storing some chunk of memory in a completely unspecified or arbitrary format to disk. It might contain pointers!

Here's another problem:

```
        datafile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(f),sizeof(f));
```

Oops, `f` doesn't point to anything. So you've now told the compiler to read data into no place in particular.

Comment: can you elaborate please? so what should it be?

Comment: You have to convert the thing you want to store into some specific format specified in terms of bytes. What should the first byte be? Should it be the numerator or the denominator? Should it be the most significant byte of the numerator or the least? You have to decide on a file format before you can write to a file. Otherwise, it will only work by luck.

Comment: I've seen that technique used before for reading file headers.  Pointers aside, you can read / write a struct directly to a file.

Comment: If a person selected `1`, but what if they didn't?

Comment: @SamDufel: You can, but you have no guarantee you've written anything meaningful. What is the first byte guaranteed to be? The answer is, nothing in particular.

Comment: So I put Fraction* f = new Fraction outside of the switch statement. So now when 3 is selected it has access to f as well, now when it's read does it store it in f, or do I need another buffer for reading?

Comment: So whatever was in f before, it is overwritten and whatever is read from the file is now in f, and when I print it it is printing the contents from the file, right?
So now i have to work on the writing function

Comment: David, saving a structure as is in a file is perfectly valid. The only two problems are (a) endianess and (b) number of bits (32/64). In this case it doesn't matter because the file is being read/written right here. Endianess and number of bits are important if you write files that are used between different versions of a software that runs on many different platforms.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: Those may be the only two problems you have encountered. That is not the same as saying those are the only problems someone else will encounter. Trying to figure out every way something not guaranteed to work at all can fail and work around each of those ways is a *terrible* way to program. You should instead use mechanisms that are guaranteed to work by the relevant standards unless you have no choice. Otherwise, new ways to fail will be found when a new CPU, OS, library, or compiler comes out.

Comment: I think you are thinking of "file format" opposed to "writing data to a file". You can have problems writing simple ASCII text to a file too (under Windows, they output \r\n for each \n you emit.) Now I wrote the [SSWF library](http://www.m2osw.com/sswf.html) and I know what I'm talking about. You can write a structure to a file just fine.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: I agree. A file is a stream of bytes. To write to a file sanely, you have to convert whatever it is you want to write to a stream of bytes.

Comment: the biggest problem with the binary read is not always the invalid pointer but that sizeof(pointer to Fraction) used in read is not equal to sizeof(Fraction) used in write